# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/doclava/Doclava : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 android build

Tags: java, android, jvm, unsupported-class-version

I am trying to build by own AOSP from google source. I follwed the steps mentioned in the Google Documents and was successfully able to build it and flash my device with the images successfully. However, I tried building it again after making some changes (basically just added some Logs to play around with it). The build errored out. I then tried to make again, it said **Javac 1.6 found. Required Javac 1.7**. I then followed the answers for this particular problem by using the following command:

```
 update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1051      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.6-oracle/bin/javac        315       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1051      manual mode
```

I then selected the option 0. I then tried to make again. This time it failed with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/doclava/Doclava : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 android build
```

After going through the all answers for this question(I found this asked so many times), I found it is because the complie time(higher version) and run time(lower version) JDK dont match and I should recompile it using Java 1.7.  How do I do that for android build? I am also surprized why I got the error "Javac 1.6 found. Required Javac 1.7." as I successfully created the build using Java 1.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case it's not the problem with javac, but with javadoc.
To check its version: `javadoc -J-version` (yes, it's weird).

So, you have to use:

```
update-alternatives --config javadoc
```

Comment: Thanks Jacek for the answer. But unfortunately I dont have the system running to check this now. So really sorry wont be able to check and accept your answer at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, soved my problem:

Answer (score 0):

This error means you're trying to load a Java "class" file that was compiled with a newer version of Java than you have installed.

For example, your `.class` file could have been compiled for `JDK 7`, and you're trying to run it with `JDK 6`.

So the solution is to either:

- Upgrade your Java runtime or
- Recompile the class if you have the source, using your local Java compiler (if you have one).

  javac FileName.java

visit this more detail: [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: Thanks Harshad. But after running the command :update-alternatives --config javac, should not it run with Java 7?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia see the link in answer.

Comment: Also, the java version in my builder server is also java 1.7. Really confused.

Comment: Thanks Harshad, I saw that answer already. But the problem is in case of the Android AOSP I cant compile indivisual file. I just have the option to make. This should use the Java 1.7 now. Or am I assuming something wrong?