# Failed of build android-8.0: FAILED: out/target/common/docs/test-api-stubs-timestamp

Tags: android, ubuntu, java

I build the android-8.0.0_r4 in Ubuntu, but failed, Following is the error information :

> FAILED: out/target/common/docs/test-api-stubs-timestamp  /bin/bash
>   out/target/common/docs/test-api-stubs-timestamp.rsp
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/doclava/Doclava :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>
> javadoc: error - fatal error 1 error

I am using the java -version check the JDK version, it looks correct.

openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Can anyone give some advise?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/doclava/Doclava : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: I check the JDK and JRE version, they are same. javac 1.8.0_45-internal.

Comment: It is resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466828/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-bad-version-number-in-class-file)

Answer (score 0):

for any other who met this problem too, please configure you default javadoc version:

update-alternatives --config javadoc

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702567/4098080